# Optimizing mobility in Firefall

Tags: firefall

I'm just starting to play Firefall and I'm trying to settle on a battleframe and build. I particularly like being highly mobile (run speed, jumping ability, etc). I've been doing some research on this, but some of the information I've seen conflict a bit, and there's some implication that some information is outdated by patches.

What selections can I make in order to optimize my mobility? I'm open to any options available, including battleframes, abilities, cores, mods, etc.

Assume a level 40 battleframe, but if there's some excellent options at lower level, highlighting them would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well for mobility the first thing you are going to want for any frame you choose is a [Run speed core](http://firefall-wiki.com/w/Battleframe_Core).

The archetypes have varying base run speeds as well, with [Recon](http://firefall-wiki.com/w/Accord_Recon) having the highest base speed. Some frames have additional mobility through skills, nearly all archetypes have a mobility skill (except engineer). Because of this, it doesn't matter which you go with, but Raptor's teleport beacon may be your best choice.

Now that you have a core and frame built for speed, let's talk perks:

There are a small handful of basic perks that increase mobility, and they are all cheap, but to get the most out of going fast, you will need to build a [tigerclaw](http://firefall-wiki.com/w/Tigerclaw) to level 20 to unlock its perk. [Dreadnaught's](http://firefall-wiki.com/w/Get_a_Move_On) level 10 perk can also be useful.

There are no modules that increase movement speed currently.

Comment: Does this mean that all of the advanced Recon frames have the same base speed as the basic Recon frame?

Comment: yes. base run speed is archetype specific, not frame specific.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternate build ... once you've been playing for a while, you'll start collecting Accord Credits.  Those can be exchanged for Red Beans (or you can pay cash for the Red Beans directly).  Red Beans can be used to purchase a reusable Glider Pad, which allows you to move much faster than walking.

However, to use it most effectively, you'll want to get high before deploying it.  Therefore, I use energy cores (I find them to be more effective than energy recharge or jump heigh cores).

As I level frames, once I get a perk point, I put it towards Prototype Pistons (+0.5 m/s run speed).  If you have a Tigerclaw to level 20, you can get Quick-Pivot Servos for 2 points (another +0.5 m/s run speed, +5% sprinting speed).  I rarely bother with Get a Move On (requires Dreadnaugt level 10;  +10% sprint if weapon is holstered; to holster, hold down 'Q' or whatever you've set your weapon switch key to), but it might be more advantagous if you're using a run speed core.

You can also get a free LGV as you progress in the game.  From a patch note a month or two ago:

> - The Accord has replaced the free battleframe trial for pilots returning for their second day of service with a permanent Cobra P-1 Light Ground Vehicle.
>
>   - The Cobra P-1 LGV will be made available 24 hours after the first game session and must be claimed within 24 hours of delivery.
>   - A blueprint to craft a Cobra P-1 LGV is still available at level 20 in Dredge for those who could not avail themselves of this gift.

Comment: My question probably wasn't clear, as I was thinking more asking along the lines of in-combat situations, so the glider pad is a bit problematic. However, I didn't include that stipulation and this has good info in it. +1